# Can not get the same signature from the keystore

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, signature

I am developing an app on eclipse. But I am not going to publish it on Play Store, users will take copies directly from me or my website.

When I try to update my app, it says there is another app installed with the same name. Uninstalling does not matter for my app. But it doesn't update without uninstalling the previous one. I just don't want users to complain about it.

Problem is; I am using the same key store and password for signing the app, but using different computers (actually three or four computers).

- Is it the cause of different signatures?
- If so, How can I get same signatures from different computers using the same key store stored in flash disk?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it the cause of different signatures? If so, How can I get same
>   signatures from different computers using the same key store stored in
>   flash disk?

**you will sign your app in a different computer but be sure to really use the same Keystore file! =).**

> When I try to update my app, it says there is another app installed
>   with the same name. Uninstalling does not matter for my app. But it
>   doesn't update without uninstalling the previous one. I just don't
>   want users to complain about it.

Remember, you have to change the `android:versionCode` into the `AndroidManifest.xml` for the newer version of your application.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.threadsample"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="2.1" >
```

Comment: I updated version code but it still asked for uninstallation. But thanks for the quick answer and info on _different computers doesn't change signature_